# Rethink-DB server cannot accept more than one other servers

Tags: virtual-machine, rethinkdb

I have setup 5 VMs on my server, to deploy and try rethink DB. These machines are named as: debianone, debiantwo, debianthree, debianfour, debianfive. On debianove I'm running this command:

```
> ./rethinkdb --bind all
```

and here what I see as the log:

```
> Running rethinkdb 2.3.2 (GCC 4.9.2)... Running on Linux 3.16.0-4-amd64
> x86_64 Loading data from directory
> /home/saman/rethinkdb-2.3.2/build/release/rethinkdb_data Listening for
> intracluster connections on port 29015 Listening for client driver
> connections on port 28015 Listening for administrative HTTP
> connections on port 8080 Listening on cluster addresses: 127.0.0.1,
> 192.168.122.154, ::1, fe80::5054:ff:fe32:214c%2 Listening on driver addresses: 127.0.0.1, 192.168.122.154, ::1, fe80::5054:ff:fe32:214c%2
> Listening on http addresses: 127.0.0.1, 192.168.122.154, ::1,
> fe80::5054:ff:fe32:214c%2 Server ready, "debianone_fqw"
> 1bed427d-e98b-4cde-b58f-269c7d07dd83
```

After that I do execute below command on debiantwo:

```
./rethinkdb --join debianone:29015  --bind all
```

and it successfully getting connected to the first server with below logs:

```
Running rethinkdb 2.3.2 (GCC 4.9.2)...
Running on Linux 3.16.0-4-amd64 x86_64
Loading data from directory /home/saman/rethinkdb-2.3.2/build/release/rethinkdb_data
Listening for intracluster connections on port 29015
Connected to server "debianone_fqw" 1bed427d-e98b-4cde-b58f-269c7d07dd83
Listening for client driver connections on port 28015
Listening for administrative HTTP connections on port 8080
Listening on cluster addresses: 127.0.0.1, 192.168.122.125, ::1, fe80::5054:ff:fe0b:df56%2
Listening on driver addresses: 127.0.0.1, 192.168.122.125, ::1, fe80::5054:ff:fe0b:df56%2
Listening on http addresses: 127.0.0.1, 192.168.122.125, ::1, fe80::5054:ff:fe0b:df56%2
Server ready, "debianone_fqw" 1bed427d-e98b-4cde-b58f-269c7d07dd83
```

Then I'm moving into debianthree and run the same above command, in order to connect to debianone. but unfortunately it stucks with below output:

```
Running rethinkdb 2.3.2 (GCC 4.9.2)...
Running on Linux 3.16.0-4-amd64 x86_64
Loading data from directory /home/saman/rethinkdb-2.3.2/build/release/rethinkdb_data
Listening for intracluster connections on port 29015
```

and at the same time I can see below errors in the debianone logs:

```
2016-05-18T16:29:42.984026809 210.309930s info: Rejected a connection from server 1bed427d-e98b-4cde-b58f-269c7d07dd83 since one is open already.
2016-05-18T16:29:43.184322734 210.510226s info: Rejected a connection from server 1bed427d-e98b-4cde-b58f-269c7d07dd83 since one is open already.
2016-05-18T16:29:43.484533404 210.810437s info: Rejected a connection from server 1bed427d-e98b-4cde-b58f-269c7d07dd83 since one is open already.
2016-05-18T16:29:43.934770639 211.260674s info: Rejected a connection from server 1bed427d-e98b-4cde-b58f-269c7d07dd83 since one is open already.
2016-05-18T16:29:44.610004320 211.935908s info: Rejected a connection from server 1bed427d-e98b-4cde-b58f-269c7d07dd83 since one is open already.
2016-05-18T16:29:45.622282451 212.948186s info: Rejected a connection from server 1bed427d-e98b-4cde-b58f-269c7d07dd83 since one is open already.
2016-05-18T16:29:47.140603565 214.466507s info: Rejected a connection from server 1bed427d-e98b-4cde-b58f-269c7d07dd83 since one is open already.
2016-05-18T16:29:49.417698306 216.743602s info: Rejected a connection from server 1bed427d-e98b-4cde-b58f-269c7d07dd83 since one is open already.
2016-05-18T16:29:52.832918941 220.158822s info: Rejected a connection from server 1bed427d-e98b-4cde-b58f-269c7d07dd83 since one is open already.
2016-05-18T16:29:58.364148418 225.690052s info: Rejected a connection from server 1bed427d-e98b-4cde-b58f-269c7d07dd83 since one is open already.
2016-05-18T16:29:58.564178142 225.890082s info: Rejected a connection from server 1bed427d-e98b-4cde-b58f-269c7d07dd83 since one is open already.
2016-05-18T16:29:58.864526591 226.190430s info: Rejected a connection from server 1bed427d-e98b-4cde-b58f-269c7d07dd83 since one is open already.
2016-05-18T16:29:59.314689583 226.640593s info: Rejected a connection from server 1bed427d-e98b-4cde-b58f-269c7d07dd83 since one is open already.
2016-05-18T16:29:59.989894570 227.315798s info: Rejected a connection from server 1bed427d-e98b-4cde-b58f-269c7d07dd83 since one is open already.
2016-05-18T16:30:01.002126962 228.328030s info: Rejected a connection from server 1bed427d-e98b-4cde-b58f-269c7d07dd83 since one is open already.
2016-05-18T16:30:02.520249008 229.846152s info: Rejected a connection from server 1bed427d-e98b-4cde-b58f-269c7d07dd83 since one is open already.
2016-05-18T16:30:04.797608179 232.123512s info: Rejected a connection from server 1bed427d-e98b-4cde-b58f-269c7d07dd83 since one is open already.
2016-05-18T16:30:08.212754870 235.538658s info: Rejected a connection from server 1bed427d-e98b-4cde-b58f-269c7d07dd83 since one is open already.
2016-05-18T16:30:13.334942743 240.660846s info: Rejected a connection from server 1bed427d-e98b-4cde-b58f-269c7d07dd83 since one is open already.
2016-05-18T16:30:21.018191367 248.344095s info: Rejected a connection from server 1bed427d-e98b-4cde-b58f-269c7d07dd83 since one is open already.
2016-05-18T16:30:32.542455984 259.868360s info: Rejected a connection from server 1bed427d-e98b-4cde-b58f-269c7d07dd83 since one is open already.
```

I still don't understand why rethinkdb is generating "debianone_fqw" id for all servers.

Has anyone ever had the same issue while deploying rethinkdb?

Answer (score 1):

This seems like a bug. I found this issue on Github https://github.com/rethinkdb/rethinkdb/issues/5456. You maywant to create an issue and let them know.

Answer (score 0):

You probably copied the RethinkDB data directory rethinkdb_data to all VMs when cloning (?) them. Every RethinkDB server has a server ID which must be unique. If the data directory is copied, all servers will have the same ID and you get the issue you're seeing.

Can you try deleting rethinkdb_data on all but one of the VMs and then start the servers again?